# Sharded ancestor entities in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, sharding, ancestor

I'm working on a GAE-based project involving a large user base (possibly millions of users). We use Datastore for persistency. Users will be identified both by username and by e-mail address, so these two properties should be unique across all entities of the kind. Because Datastore doesn't support unique fields other than ID, we need transactions to ensure uniqueness of these fields when new users are registered. And in order to have transactions, User entities need to be enclosed in entity groups.

Having large entity groups is not recommended, as pointed out [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention). Therefore, given a possible large number of stored users, I'm thinking of putting them into multiple smaller entity groups. Each group would have a common parent with ID generated from the two unique fields (a piece of the MD5 sum for instance). Inserting a new user could look like this (in Python):

```
@ndb.transactional
def register_new_user(login, email, full_name) :
    # validation code omitted
    user = User(login = login, email = email, full_name = full_name)
    group_id = a_simple_hash(login, email)
    group_key = ndb.Key('UserGroup', group_id)
    query = User.query(ancestor = group_key).filter(ndb.OR(User.login = login, User.email = email))
    if not query.get() :
        user.put()
```

One problem I see with this solution is that it will be impossible to get a User by ID alone. We'd have to use complete entity keys.

Are there any other cons of such approach? Anyone tried something similar?

**EDIT**

As I've been pointed out in comments, a hash like the one outlined above would not work properly because it would only prevent registering users having non-unique e-mails together with non-unique usernames matching those e-mails. It would work if the hash was computed based on a single field.

Nevertheless, I find the concept of such sharding interesting by itself and perhaps worth of discussion.

Comment: Have you heard of get_or_insert: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert

Comment: Yes, but - as far as I understand - this method only ensures uniqueness of the key name. I don't want to use usernames or e-mail addresses as entity identifiers.

Comment: Your code will only prevent pairs of users with both the same login and same email. Duplicates of either one will be possible!

Comment: @Greg Yeah, it occured to me as well in the meantime. I will edit the question and point this out.

Comment: Eventual consistency doesn't mean that you "have a chance not to find a user when you query for it". It means that you might not be able to retrieve your entity **in the very seconds** after your write. Transactions are not NEEDED here. See my answer

Comment: By the way, sharding is a necessity created by write throughput limitations, not reads! Reads are always easier inside an entity group.

Answer (score 0):

An e-mail address is owned by a user and unique. So there is a very small change, somebody will (try to) use the same email address.

So my approch would be: get_or_insert a new login, which makes it easy to login (by key) and next verify if the e-mail address is unique.

If it not unique you can discard or .....do something else

Entity groups have meaning for transactions. I'am interested in your planned transactions, because I do not understand your entity group key hash. Which entities will be part of the entity group, and why?

A user with the same login will be part of another entity group, If i do understand your hash?
It looks like your entity group holds a single entity.

Comment: I would really like to have not-easily-guessable user IDs. If there's no way to achieve this together with unique usernames/e-mails, i'll do this like you suggest (usernames as keys) or just drop the username field altogether. The idea of sharding came to me as a possible solution to the problem of unique fields and transactions. Users were meant to be groupped by hashes, so that when a new user registers, we could find the group where the potential username/e-mail conflict may occur. I was mistaken with the hash concept, though, and it won't work as expected for more than one field.

Comment: Using a regex you can ask for userd id with 8 characters and .... But you also can use Openid like Stackoverflow, the new Openid Connect or Facebook connect.

Comment: non guessable userid's are also hard for people to remember.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you're overthinking here : what's the probability of having two users register with the same username at the same time ?
Very slim. Eventual consistency is good enough for this case, as you don't nanosecond precision...
unless you plan to have more users than facebook, with people registering every second.

Registering with the same email is virtually impossible for different users, since the check has already been done by the email provider for you!
Only a user could try to open two accounts with the same email address. Eventual consistency is good enough for this query too.

Your user entities each belong to their own entity group.

**Actually in most use cases, your User is the most obvious root entity** : people use the datastore because they need scalability, and most of the time huge scale is needed for user oriented apps.